# Обёртки для классов C++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Необходимо написать класс, содержащий std::queue, и реализовать для него обёртки над front, push.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

class Test
{
  std::queue <int> q;
};
```

Каким образом можно реализовать обёртки на front и push?)

Comment: Можно начать с написания пустого класса.

Comment: можешь унаследоваться и заменить эти методы или добавить к ним доп функционал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял, как это сделать. Оказалось, что это очень легко)

```
#include <queue>

class Test
{
private:
  std::queue <int> q;

public:

  void front()
  {
    q.front();
  }

  void push(const int elem)
  {
    q.push(elem);
  }
};
```